# Include Full Post Details In /users/{id}/timeline

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, rate-limit, timeline

I have a feature request.  I'm trying to pull the recent activity about a user from the API.  So I'm parsing /users/{id}/timeline.  But that only gives me meta-information about the activity.  So then, for each result I need to re-call the `/questions/{id}`, `/answers/{id}` and `/comments/{id}` calls to get the actual data about what happened.

This is causing me to hit the rate-limit because instead of getting everything I need in 1 api call for the past 100 items, I need to hit the API 101 times...

So, I'm requesting a configuration parameter added to the timeline api call to allow the API to return the details of the referenced post for the following types:

- askoranswered
- comment

Basically, the containing information should be similar to calling the appropriate API (`/questions/{id}`, `/answers/{id}` and `/comments/{id}`) with both `body=true` and `comments=true` (for questions and answers).

I'd suggest: `fullposts=true` for the API parameter, and add it to the result under `post: {}`, the type for which can be determined by the `post_type` that's already in the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using API v2 or not, but you do know that the /questions/{ids} endpoint (as well as /answers and /comments) in v2 will take multiple ids in one call.  If you parse through the timeline, and then need more information, you can keep a list of all the question, answer, and comment ID's, and then join them together to make just one API call for each type.  This is covered in the docs under [Vectorized Requests](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors) (I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do though, and if so, I apologize)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be making more than 4 requests in this case.

- fetch a page of /users/{ids}/timeline
- group the ids by type (question, answers, comments)

  - since the max pagesize fo users/{ids}/timeline is 100, we know there are < 100 of each id*
- make 1 query each with the appropriate ids to /questions/{ids}, /answers/{ids}, and /comments/{ids}

This is the point behind [vectorized requests](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors) (link is to the 2.0 docs, though I gather you're using v1.1; the concept is the same).

<sub>*No method takes more than 100 ids in an {ids} url parameter.</sub>

Comment: I am using v2.0, but it winds up becoming screwy because I need to maintain ordering of the sets.  I can definitely do it, the point was that it would be a whole lot easier (and more robust) if the data was returned in the original query, hence the feature request...

Comment: It's declined, because it's possible to construct the data with other queries?  Even though it's not trivial at all and requires a not-insignificant amount of logic to complete (whereas implementing it at the API level would be far easier)?  Ultimately it's your product and decision, but I can't say that I see the logic in summarily declining it like that...

Comment: @Kevin, about the point of vectorized requests: the point of filters is to choose what you want.